# How to use Moveit for planning circular path with a robotic arm

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
I want to draw a circle or other geometric object with a robotic arm ,but MoveIt seems only supports the path constraints designed to  from point A to point B.
How to use MoveIt to solve it? Or is there any other package of ROS to solve this problom? 
Any advice?
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211343/how-to-use-moveit-for-planning-circular-path-with-a-robotic-arm/) by [sansherlock](https://answers.ros.org/users/20629/sansherlock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-06-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this should be possible using the available tools within move_group and using them in the appropriate order.

- Compute a circular cartesian path as
  a vector of poses
- Compute    corresponding joint space cartesian path using the
  [cartesian path service capability](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/blob/jade-devel/move_group/src/default_capabilities/cartesian_path_service_capability.cpp)
- Send the path off to MoveIt!  to execute

[It sounds](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moveit-users/MOoFxy2exT4) like this might be problematic because of missing time parametrization of the trajectory.

As stated by @paul-jurczak, another option is looking at the [Cartesian Path Planner Plug-In for MoveIt!](http://rosindustrial.org/news/2014/9/5/cartesian-path-planner-plug-in-for-moveit)

For DRC, we implemented our own pipeline for generating cartesian motion based on a Action request that specifies the rotation center pose and then rotates the given endeffector around it. Relevant pieces of code:

- [Generate waypoint
  poses](https://github.com/team-vigir/vigir_manipulation_planning/blob/master/vigir_moveit_utils/include/vigir_moveit_utils/constrained_motion_utils.h#L49)
- [Use of function inside Action
  callback](https://github.com/team-vigir/vigir_manipulation_planning/blob/master/vigir_move_group/src/manipulation_action_capability.cpp#L612)

This likely is a bit heavyweight if you're just interested in doing  a circular motion, but might serve for inspiration.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2022-08-13**:
Update: The Pilz Industrial Motion Planner offers CIRC motions. It was added to MoveIt in 2020

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was just searching for an answer to the same question. The solution seems to rely on a Cartesian path. Have a look at [computeCartesianPath](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroup.html#ad6b02d15000d5b17c89b15a0f744b47c). There is more in [Cartesian Path Planner Plug-In for MoveIt!](http://rosindustrial.org/news/2014/9/5/cartesian-path-planner-plug-in-for-moveit) blog post.

---

Originally posted by [Paul Jurczak](https://answers.ros.org/users/9766/paul-jurczak/) with karma: 31 on 2015-09-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sansherlock](https://answers.ros.org/users/20629/sansherlock/) on 2015-09-17**:
Thank you.After a long time using of Moveit,I feel that ROS does not  do a lot of  work for controlling a robot arm .Not enough funtions.

- List item

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just solved this problem for the TIAGo robot and the panda robot.

I used ComputeCartesianPath() from the Moveit! API and created waypoints using components of the position of the end effector with respect to the centre:

```
for( theta in 0 to 90)
 target_pose.position. y = r*sin(theta)
 target_pose.position. x = r*cos(theta)
 waypoints.pushback(target_pose)
```

Then call the ComputeCartesianPath() using required syntax!

---

Originally posted by [odd-incubus](https://answers.ros.org/users/85378/odd-incubus/) with karma: 11 on 2022-04-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1